# ASPX API is getting blocked in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, api, jquery-ajaxq

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://<api URL>/xml_full_new_york.aspx",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: true,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find('stockquotes').each(function () {
                    var sTitle = $(this).find('CurrentPrice').text();
                    $('#stockTickerNYSE').text("$" + sTitle);
                });
            }
        });
```

In Google Chrome the above API is getting blocked. But it is working fine in IE browser. In Chrome console I found the error:
"Pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

Answer (score 0):

It's [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue, you need to add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in your back-end code.

Comment: This is a third party API, We don't have access to the backend code of that API.

Comment: @ManjunathKondikoppa if it is third party API then you have to talk with them.

Comment: Thank You, Kiran.